# Urn model for birth statistic

Tags: probability, intuition, polya-urn-model

I have an exercise which reads like this:

> A hospital has a statistic about how many boys and girls are born. 40% of all newborns are female, the others are male. Calculate the probability for the next baby to be male and for the next two newborns to have differing sexes.

My confusion is about whether or not this is an "urne experiment" with or without putting the balls back into the urn after one draw. Obviously, one birth will not affect the next one. On the other hand, I get the feeling, that if one assumes the statistic to be correct, I can expect that after a male baby is born that it is ever so slightly less probable that the next one will be male, that is with $< 60\%$ probability.

### Edit

Some clarification about what I am confused about in response to @lulu's comment: 
That is true, also from a purely biological/physics standpoint. However, I was wondering about whether mathematically removing the ball after the first draw makes a statement about how reliable the statistic is. Suppose there are 10 children born in succession, all boys. It does not become more "probable" that a girl is born with the next birth, because "probability does not have a memory" - i.e. the sex is determined purely random. On the other hand one can argue, that after 10 boys it should be more likely that a girl is born, since otherwise the statistics would not add up in the long  run.

Comment: I think it is unreasonable to imagine that the gender of one child depends on the gender of another.  If the given data is all we know, I think one has to make the assumption that each birth is (independently) female with probability $.4$

Comment: In reality there may be a positive correlation between the genders of successive births, since there may be identical twins.  But I doubt it is expected in this question

Comment: @lulu I have added some clarification.

Comment: No, there is no ":memory" attached to the iterated trials.  However, Bayes' Theorem  (and common sense) would tell us that if the data doesn't match our assumption over a lot of samples, then perhaps our assumption is wrong.  The $\frac 12$ estimate is quite crude, after all...and indeed, the data does not back it up.  The probability of a male birth (independent of other factors) in the U.S. is about $.49$ and it is different in different regions (even if explanations aren't clear).